# Why does a "for of" loop work and a regular "for" loop not work?

Tags: javascript, loops, duplicates

I get the wrong answer for this [leetcode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate/) using a regular `for` loop to iterate over the nums array but the for of loop gives me the correct answer. The goal is to return true or false on whether or not the nums array has any duplicates.

```
// for of loop, answer is accepted
var containsDuplicate = function(nums) {
let set = new Set()

    for (let i of nums) {
        if (!set.has(i)) {
            set.add(i) 
        } else {
            return true
        }
    
    }
    return false
};

// regular for loop, answer not accepted
var containsDuplicate = function(nums) {
    let set = new Set()

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (!set.has(i)) {
            set.add(i) 
        } else {
            return true
        }
    
    }
    return false
};
```

Comment: You talk about 2 versions of code, but only posted one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable `i` is different in the two examples.  In the working code, `i` is each value from the array.  In the failing code, `i` is each *index* of the array.  And the index will alway be unique regardless of what’s in the array.

You can observe this by adding `console.log(i)` inside your loop and running your own tests on the code.  (You are strongly encouraged to always test your code and observe the behavior, *especially* if the code isn't doing what you expect.)

In the `for` loop change the use of `i` to `nums[i]` to reference the array elements:

```
if (!set.has(nums[i])) {
  set.add(nums[i]) 
} else {
  return true
}
```